# Change Background Color of Clicked Child in Expandable ListView Android

Tags: android, background-color, expandablelistview

I want to change the background color of the child which is clicked in an ExpandableListView.
That is, when any child is clicked, it's background color should get changed.
I am trying to go it in this way but it selects some other row, not the one which has been clicked.

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    parent.getChildAt(childPosition).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    return false;
}
```

Please tell me what I might be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about lets say you try to directly refer your view and set the background like this,

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yep! This works, but the color persists even when another child is clicked. My aim here is to highlight which child has been selected, so when another is selected, others should get back to normal.

Comment: Then you have to manually find out which child is clicked and set the color to it and remove the color from the previously selected child. You can either maintain the position of which child is being clicked or use some other better strategy to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved it.

```
View _lastColored;
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    _groupPosition = groupPosition;


    if(_lastColored != null)
    {
    _lastColored.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    _lastColored.invalidate();
    }
    _lastColored = v;
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(214, 214, 214));


    return false;
}
```

Comment: GOOD PIECE OF CODE THANKS!

Comment: @NiteshVerma : Thank you! Glad it could be of help. :)

Comment: @Swayam : Nice code.But Is it possible to change the background color of a child view outside the onChildClick() ?

Comment: @ParagKadam : Can you please elaborate what you mean by "outside the onChildClick()"? I mean, you would need the reference of the view. As long as you have the reference of the view whose background you want to change, you can do it anywhere.

Comment: I saved the view that I got inside the onChildClick() , and I tried to set background color to it but unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: @Swayam : Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044616/change-background-color-of-clicked-child-in-expandable-listview-android-outside

Comment: @Swayam :It worked but the child selected at one group is also selected in other group.How to solve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't really happen. And if it does, add a check for groupPosition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


    Object obj = parent.getTag();
      if(obj instanceof View){
             ((View) obj).findViewByID(<id of main ViewGroup of row>).setBackgroundColor(Color.<your normal color>);
         }


    v.findViewByID(<id of main ViewGroup of row>).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);


 parent.setTag(v);



    return false;
}


parent.getChildAt(childPosition).findViewByID(<id of main ViewGroup of row >).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

or 


v.findViewByID(<id of main ViewGroup of row>).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

for second one [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html#onChildClick(android.widget.ExpandableListView, android.view.View, int, int, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html#onChildClick%28android.widget.ExpandableListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20long%29)

Comment: Can you please explain the findViewByID part ?

Comment: I had problem with making item selceted this way is when I was using in simple list that if you are using convert view in getView then on scrlloing down it shows other view as selected.......

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I already used Andro's technique and worked it out.