# Change Background Color of Clicked Child in Expandable ListView Android outside the onChildClick() method

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have one Activity and two fragments - Fragment1 and Fragment2. When the app starts Fragment1 gets attached to my activity, this fragment consists of a ExpandableListView. When I click on any of the childs it changes the background color of the childview and Fragment1 gets replaced with Fragment2. When I go back from my Fragment2 to Fragment one, it should show me the changed childView background colour.How do I achieve it?

This is what I have done,
My Fragment 1 code :-

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rooms_frag, container, false);
            ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
            MoviesAdapter adapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity());
            expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if(flag)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+ MainActivity.grpPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                expandableListView.expandGroup(MainActivity.grpPosition);
               // myView is a static TextView declared in the fragment class itself                
                myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 245, 245));//Here I have tried to change the background color but does not get changed(No errors or warnings either)
            }
            expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    MainActivity.grpPosition = groupPosition;
                    MainActivity.chldPosition = childPosition;
                    SpotlightsFragment myFrag = new SpotlightsFragment();
                    String childName = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
                    String parentName = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
                    TextView childView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.child_txt);
                    myView = childView;
                    childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 245, 245));
                   return false;
            }
        });
        return  view;
    }
```

Fragment2 :-

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment1 myFrag = new Fragment1();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = MainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frag, myFrag);
        transaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend the transition betweeen fragments to be managed by the activity (MainActivity in this case). The least one fragment knows the other, the better.

You should make an interface, make the activity implement that interface and the second fragment will call the interface methods through getActivity() casted to that interface.
In the interface you can change between fragments.

That would be something like this

GoBackToList.java

```
public interface GoBackToList {
    public void andHighlightPosition(int group, int position);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity implements GoBackToList {
    ...
    private Fragment1 f1;

    @Override
    public void andHighlightPosition(int group, int position) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frag, f1);
        transaction.commit();
        f1.highlight(group, position);
    }
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    ...
    private int previousHighlightGroup;
    private int previousHighlightPosition;

    public void highlight(int group, int position) {
    // Reset previous highlight color
    expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(previousHighlightGroup, previousHighlightPosition)
            .findViewById(R.id.child_txt).setBackgroundColor(ORIGINAL_COLOR);
    // Highlight new view
    expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(group, position)
            .findViewById(R.id.child_txt).setBackgroundColor(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
    // Store values
    previousHighlightGroup = group;
    previousHighlightPosition = position;
   }
}
```

Fragment2.java

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        ((GoBackToList)getActivity())).andHighlight(currentGroup, currentPosition);
        }
     });
```

Comment: I will try your solution but before that can you tell me why myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 245, 245)); does not set the required color?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of Fragment1 each time and inflating a new view. I would say that myView is a reference to an old view

Comment: expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(group, position) returns a String not a view.

Answer (score 0):

When you are replacing the first fragment with the second, you should store the required which index was clicked in **`onSaveInstanceState()`**. In that way, when your fragment is created again when you return to it, the index can be found in the **`savedInstanceState`** bundle. And then, using that index, you can set the color of that item.

Comment: Cant put the index in onSaveInstanceState() because in my case it doesn't get called in the first place.

Comment: onSaveInstance ins't getting called when you are replacing the fragment?

Comment: Yes it does not get called. What should I do to make sure that onSaveInstance gets called?

Comment: OnSaveInstanceState of the fragment gets called when the onPause of the activity gets called.